# Why does lighttpd fail to install on Raspberry pi?

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-wheezy, lighttpd

Here's what I try :

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo apt-get update

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/dists/wheezy/main/binary-armhf/Packages  401  Unauthorized


pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo apt-get install lighttpd

Install these packages without verification [y/N]? y
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy/main libfam0 armhf 2.7.0-17
  401  Unauthorized
```

I'm given just a couple of the problems I encounter. I'm not allowed more than 2 links and the error messages contain links.

Any help would be super.

Final goal is to be able to take a pic using my webcam while I'm on vacation..

Comment: Problem was that I was at work, where an arbitrary device cannot simple access the internet without authentication. I just realized this..

So, a test would be 

curl -D - <google http>

which comes back with

HTTP/1.0 302 Moved
Location: http://x.y.z.a:15871/cgi-bin/authenticate.cgi?ws-session=2778187179
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache

itle></head>
<body bgcolor="#ffffff">
<center><h1><font color="#ff0000">HTTP Error 403 - Forbidden</font></h1>
<b>You do not have permission to access the document or program you requested.
</b></center>
</body></html>

Comment: Then, you can do :

curl -D - --basic -u user.name http://x.y.z.a:15871/cgi-bin/authenticate.cgi?ws-session=2778187179

Enter host password for user 'user.name' :
HTTP/1.0 302 Moved
Content-Length: 0
Location: <google>


And then, all is good

Comment: use nginx instead. it is as lightweight but much more powerful than lighhtpd... `apt-get install nginx`

Comment: I have previously tried to use lighttpd but the configuration file kept deleting itself. I would recommend using thttpd if you want to keep it simple. Use apt-get install thttpd, make a folder called www in your home directory then use thttpd -d ~/www to start your server! Put make a file called index.html with some html code it to get started. Enter the ip of your pi into your brower to view the page.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your internet connection work through a proxy device that requires authentication. You have to set up proxy credentials for connection. For apt you can set up the authentication just like this :

```
# Create a proxy config file for proxy if does not exist
sudo nano /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01proxy

# Add the following line into 01proxy config file
Acquire::http::proxy "http://user:pass@host:port/";
```

Then try `apt-get update; apt-get install lighttpd`